# Upsert in PostgreSQL with EXECUTEMANY and Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to update on conflict in PostgreSQL while using `executemany`.

Here is my table setup:

```
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,        
        role VARCHAR(50)        
        )
    ''')
```

And here is the upsert query:

```
roles = ((1, "R1"), (2, "R2"), (3, "R3"), (4, "R4"), 
(5, "R5"), (6, "R6"))
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO roles VALUES 
    ($1 ,$2)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
        DO UPDATE SET role = $2
    """, 
    roles);
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
cur.executemany("""
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedParameter: there is no parameter $1
LINE 3:     ($1 ,$2)
```

Comment: Because you are not using correct parameters. Read this [Parameter Passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters). Hint you need `%s` or `%<name>s`.

Comment: I found a tutorial: https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-insert-update-delete-table-data-to-perform-crud-operations/

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found a way to do it. The problem for me was that `%s` was vague because there were two placeholders.  I needed a way to specify that the column role was to be updated with the second variable. `EXCLUDED.role` does that. Hope this helps someone else.

```
roles = ((1, "R1"), (2, "R2"), (3, "R3"), (4, "R4"), 
(5, "R5"), (6, "R6"))
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO roles VALUES 
    (%s ,%s)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
        DO UPDATE SET role = (EXCLUDED.role)
    """, 
    roles);
```

Comment: Actually there where three placeholders and the second  `$2` could be replaced with `%s`. Though that would mean repeating the second item in each tuple so: `(1, "R1", "R1")`. The better way is to use a list of dicts: `[{"id': 1, "role": "R1"}, ...)` and then do `%(id)s` and %s(role)s`.  I generally use this form because 1) You do not have to repeat the values. 2) You don't run into tuple indexing errors.